# Changing df column format

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `dict`:

```
diction= [
    {
        "name": "x",
        "no": 10,
        "buy_sell": "buy",
        "date": "10/07/2018"
    }
    ,
    {
        "name": "y",
        "no": 10,
        "buy_sell": "sell",
        "date": "11/07/2018"
    }]
```

This has an undesired date format which is `%d/%m/%Y` whereas I would like it to be `%Y-%m-%d`.

What I have tried in order to change the format was to turn the `dict` into a `pd.DataFrame` and after that change the format of the column `date` (and then turn it again to a `dict`), here is what I tried:

```
tabla = pd.DataFrame(diction)
tabla['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tabla['date'])
tabla['date'] = tabla['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I don't know why it seems to be confusing the day with the month and is throwing out the output:

```
  buy_sell       date      name    no
0      buy    2018-10-07     x      10
1     sell    2018-11-07     y      10
```

My desired output would be:

```
  buy_sell       date      name    no
0      buy    2018-07-10     x      10
1     sell    2018-07-11     y      10
```

with the format `%Y-%m-%d`.

Comment: `tabla['date']=pd.to_datetime(tabla['date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse the dates, you could use

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date, dayfirst=True)
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to change the format of the dates in the dictionaries you could simply:

```
for d in diction:
    d['date'] = '{}-{}-{}'.format(d['date'][6:10], d['date'][3:5], d['date'][:2])
```

No need for pandas and converting data twice.